# Python -- when should a class have-a rather than be-a?

Tags: design, object-oriented, python, inheritance

This is related to ["Extends is evil" vs. OCP?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/210418/extends-is-evil-vs-ocp) but separate because the idea of "implement the interface" doesn't exist in Python.

I'm writing a class to pull some data off a webpage. It's going to need to hold on to a cookie for authentication, so I'm going to use a `requests.Session` object in some form. I'm never sure how to approach this -- what's the appropriate choice here?

```
class FooFetcher(requests.Session):
    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__()
```

or

```
class FooFetcher(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
```

?

The former seems to end up with `FooFetcher` having way more public methods than it needs to. The latter looks like it might be unnecessarily convoluted, since pretty much every method of `FooFetcher` is going to involve a call to a method of that `Session` object, plus maybe some parsing of JSON that it finds.

Comment: Would you like to have-a wallet, or be-a wallet?  If you chose have-a than the person should have-a wallet. Should your penguins have-a animal or be-a animal? ...and so on and so forth.

Comment: Fair enough -- it just seems strange to me in the case like this one where the only thing that matters about `FooFetcher` is the session. If the only interaction I have with my parents is to ask them for money, it might make sense to say that they `are-a` wallet rather than `have-a` wallet, from my perspective.

Comment: There's no reason you can't implement an interface that provides facilities from the things you *have*, if you have-a wallet, then perhaps the person interface should have a TakeMoney method on it. In fact many institutions presume we do all have this interface method implemented :|

Comment: Note that in your first example, the `__init__` method is entirely redundant and can be omitted entirely.

Comment: If _the only thing that matters about `FooFetcher` is the session_, is it even really a class? You can just pass your session into a bunch of free functions, if there's no other state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to look at the *calling* code.  Is there any code that currently uses a `requests.Session` object that you want to be able to pass in a `FooFetcher` instead?  If not, then use composition.

Answer (score 1):

Your particular example strongly suggests HAS-A relationship, thus, composition, because FooFetcher is not a Session.

BTW, Python does have multiple inheritance, and sometimes functionality can be added using mix-ins.

For example, you may have Sessioning and add it as a mix-in:

```
 class FooFetcher(BaseFetcher, Sessioning):
     ...
```

Returning to your second example, I think, session should be explicit:

```
class FooFetcher(object):
    def __init__(self, session):
        self.session = session
```

This way it's easier to test and maintain the code.